# Repair Disk Permissions in Terminal seems to hang

Tags: terminal, macos, time-machine, disk-utility, permission

OK, I tried following (OS X Yosemite) the instructions here

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538

And I went into Terminal and typed in the following

```
diskutil resetUserPermissions / id -u
```

But now it's been showing a line of little rotating slash marks for a good couple of hours. I wondered if it's just one of those processes that takes a ton of time like when you do some kinds of file repair or whatever.

I also wondered what would happen if I interrupt this and try restarting. I have a TM backup so worst case I can restore from there and try again.

The Mac BTW is a 2010 Macbook Air. So it's about at the limit of what can run Yosemite at all.

Comment: Was there a problem with your user account file attributes that needing fixing? Also, my first thought for 2010 vintage Mac is: Is the original hard drive failing?

Comment: I tried  permissions repair via disk utility, after interrupting the process. That seems to work--at least it tells me so. The drive is SSD - I guess it could be failing but I made a backup. The reason I was doing this is because I tried transferring the photos with migration assistant to a new mac (late model Air) and it said it couldn't repair permissions and transfer most of the photos. See this Q here (only partly answered) https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378560/moving-photos-to-a-new-mac-from-an-old-one-issues-with-permissions-and-icloud/378573?noredirect=1#comment511215_378573